# Как заставить ИИ слышать звуки и реагировать на них?

Tags: c#, unity3d, аудио, искусственный-интеллект

Как заставить бота слышать звуки (например, выстрелы разной громкости из-за разных видов оружия), и реагировать на них, если он их слышит. Так же ИИ не должен слышать через стены.

Comment: Сайт на русском, оставьте только русскоязычный вариант

Comment: Фактически NPC ничего не видят и не слышат. Всё реализуется через программную логику. Можно подглядеть как реализуется "смотрение" и аналогично запрограммировать звуки, например добавляя невидимый (для игрока) объект с соответствующими параметрами.

Comment: @Adokenai можно немного уточнить? В вашем ответе вы сказали про очевидные вещи, но никакой конкретики, можете привести примеры кода? Спасибо.

Comment: @Ilya Smirnoff увы, конкретики нет, поэтому комментарий, а не ответ. В своё время смог создать мод на игру S.T.A.L.K.E.R, но там поиск видимых объектов выполняется вызовом отдельной функции, поэтому её реализацию я не знаю.

Comment: А для чего это собственно нужно?) Какой функционал должен выполнять бот? Опишите эту часть вашей игры.

Comment: @Artik Slayer это же очевидно: если пистолет стреляет, то присесть; если свист снаряда - бежать; если кто-то пукнул - зажать нос.

Comment: @Adokenai а нельзя ли тогда по пересечениям коллайдера объектов считать или нечто подобное(или raycast)? Мол если снаряд в зоне "видимости" персонажа за n-нное кол-во метров, то сделать вышеупомянутые действия. Дело в том что, пока ещё не сталкивался с реагированием на звук.

Comment: @ArtikSlayer бот должен реагировать паникой на звуки выстрелов, если он их слышит

Comment: @Artik Slayer "ИИ не должен слышать через стены". То есть приседание только после пробития. При условии, что NPC уже не прибило. ТС пишет про панику, что нелепо, хотя и очевидно.

Comment: @ArtikSlayer ну смотри, у меня, к примеру, есть радиус, внутри которого слышно звук, но он не будет работать если есть препятствия. Официальный туториал юнити предлагает использовать NavMesh и считать длину пути до цели, но по-моему это какой-то "колхозный" метод, и я надеялся найти какой-нибудь другой. Было бы интересно, например, узнать громкость звука в любой конкретной точке в пространстве с учётом рельефа местности и всех мешающих прохождению звука помех

Answer (score 3):

В юнити нету родной возможности что бы заставить ИИ слышать звуки. Но это дело можно имитировать. Наприме как-то так:

```
// attached to object that has audio source

var objArray: GameObject[];
var volumeOffset: float = 5;

function PlaySound() {
  audio.Play();
  var sndRadius = audio.volume*volumeOffset;
  BroadcastSoundWave(sndRadius);
}

function BroadcastSoundWave (sndRadius: float) {
  var i: int = 0;
  var args: Array = new Array (gameObject, audio);
  for (i=0; i<objArray.length; i++) {
    var obj = objArray[i].transform;
    var dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, obj.position);
    if (dist < sndRadius) {
      obj.BroadcastMessage("heardSound", args,
        SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    }
  }
}
```

Или, подобные по идеи реализации.

А еще есть вот такой ассет: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/ai/realtime-hearing-ai-28492 который можно использовать в том числе и под эти нужды.

хотя вообще советую погуглить что-то вроде "unity AI reaction on sound", может найдешь и более интересный код

Comment: Так уж сложилось, что Unity уже в принципе не переваривает свою вариацию js'а. Так что данный ответ едва ли принесете пользу вопрошающему или кому-то другому в будущем.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker да не важно что я JS скопировал, здесь подход важно подсмотреть. Код не на столько сложный что бы возникли сложности его переписать на шарп. Но, как минимум, теперь есть направление, в котором ТС может думать :) PS: а вообще я и сам JS очень недолюбливаю... Хоть в юнити, хоть без.

Comment: Ну я намекал на хотя бы пояснение, что этот код скорее относится к псевдокоду и Unity больше не запустится на нем.

Comment: @Andrew ответ хороший, но он не особо решает проблему с разной громкостью звуков из-за разных видов оружия, например. Да, конечно, можно вручную каждому типу оружия присвоить его громкость, но хотелось бы, конечно, автоматически всё это скриптом выполнять. Обидно что юнити не имеет такого функционала :D

Comment: Ты можешь анализировать громкость звука на соурсе в даный момент и изменять размер радиуса круга в зависимости от этого. Например максимальная громкость -- максимальный радиус(который равен радиусу самого аудиосоурса, например). минимальная громкость - пара метров. Можно посмотреть тут немного информации по теме аудио: https://answers.unity.com/questions/157940/getoutputdata-and-getspectrumdata-they-represent-t.html

Comment: Ну и для оптимизации обновлять информацию, скажем, раз на 3-5-7 fixedUpdate-ов.